# No funciona sentencia SQL para hacer un ticket, ayuda

Tags: mysql

No funciona me marca este error:

> ## 1054 - La columna 'clientes.idcliente' en field list es desconocida

```
Select rentas.idrenta, clientes.idcliente, clientes.nombre as 'Nombre del cliente', autos.marcamodelo 
from rentas inner join detalle_renta on rentas.idrenta = detalle_renta.idrenta 
inner join autos on detalle_renta.idauto = autos.idauto
inner join usuarios on rentas.idusuario = usuarios.idusuario 
where rentas.idrenta = '1' 
group by rentas.idrenta,'Nombre del cliente', marcamodelo
```

Comment: Haces mención a la tabla `clientes` pero la has declarado en ninguna parte del `from`.  Sin conocer la estructura de las tablas y como se relacionan no se puede saber como debería ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer te falta agregar a la tabla clientes a tu consulta
ya que por eso no te reconoce el campo clientes.idcliente

```
inner join  clientes on clientes.idcliente=rentas.idcliente
```

Comment: sabes como iria acomodado, no soy muy bueno en sql :(

Comment: revisa con que tabla tiene relación clientes

Comment: esta relacionada con mi tabla de rentas

Comment: entonces solo agrégale  el inner join clientes on clientes.idcliente=rentas.idcliente,   verifica si el campo con el que se relaciona esta definido como idcliente si no es así pon el que corresponde